# GCloud compute tunnel always shows warning telling to install numpy

Tags: python, numpy, gcloud, ssh-tunnel

I am setting up a tunnel with gcloud from a remote machine with:

```
gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel ...
```

Everything used to be fine until a few days ago when it started to show the following message:

```
To increase the performance of the tunnel, consider installing NumPy. To install
NumPy, see: https://numpy.org/install/.
After installing NumPy, run the following command to allow gcloud to access
external packages:
  export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1
```

I did exactly what it says, I have installed numpy with `pip install numpy` and exported the variable, but the warning doesn't go away.

Have you experienced this?

Comment: You might have a package install location problem. Check where **pip** installed NumPy. Probably in your user's site-packages folder. Where is **gcloud** installed and its **site-packages** folder?

Comment: Have you follow this guide? https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#increasing_the_tcp_upload_bandwidth

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by [@john-hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley), it may be due to Python installed in Library directory, as in case of universal installed for macOS, and gcloud installed in user's home directory as advised by GCP documentation. This can be fixed by re-installing either gcloud or python3. You can find installation locations by running in terminal:

```
which gcloud
which python3
```

In my case it was easier to reinstall gcloud to Library. The only drawback though is that I need to run component install with sudo as:

```
sudo /Library/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud components install ...
```

Another cause might be that you are using ZSH shell and not Bash. [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#increasing_the_tcp_upload_bandwidth) provides the command to be added into .bashrc file with remark that unless added it will have effect only in the current terminal instance.

In my case after reinstalling gcloud to the Library and running the above command, I stopped receiving the NumPy warning in that specific tab but it was present in other tabs.
I ran the following command to add the line to Zsh:

```
echo "export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1" >> ~/.zshrc
```

And the warning has disappeared. I hope that the above will help others.
Also please take note of an important comment below by [@Jobu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913816/jobu)

Comment: They've started shipping their own python with gcloud, so you have to install numpy into that python env.  

From the listed instructions.  https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#increasing_the_tcp_upload_bandwidth


`$(gcloud info --format="value(basic.python_location)") -m pip install numpy`  

Note the leading $ is not the shell prompt, but part of the command extracting the path to their shipped python.

Comment: Thank you @Jobu I stripped the preceeding $ and got issues. It didn't work until I found your comment.

Comment: I think I was wrong that they ship their own python.  Just that they've changed how they pick a python to use.   You can also set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON env var to something like `/my/path/to/bin/python3`

Answer (score 0):

As @Jobu mentioned in one of the comments above, you would need to use:

```
$(gcloud info --format="value(basic.python_location)") -m pip install numpy
```

if you get the warning again, you might need to set this env var for your shell:

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1
```

the warning might still appear after all this, if your numpy version has fallen behind. Update it with:

```
$(gcloud info --format="value(basic.python_location)") -m pip install numpy --upgrade --break-system-packages
```